# How to send a Java Long value from json

Tags: java, json, spring

I'm trying to send a POST request to an Spring RestController with a request body. In the object there is a Long value but it is not arriving to the endpoint with the other parameters.
The class used as `@RequestBody` is this one:

```
@Entity
public class Curso {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "titulo")
    private String titulo;
    @Column(name = "nivel")
    private String nivel;
    @Column(name = "nhoras")
    private String nhoras;
    @Column(name = "profesorid")
    private Long profesorid;
    [...]
    public Long getProfesorid() {
        return profesorid;
    }
    public void setProfesorid(Long profesor) {
        this.profesorid = profesorid;
    }
}
```

The endpoint in the class annotated with `@RestController`, is this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/crear-curso", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addCurso(@RequestBody Curso curso) {
        cursoService.addCurso(curso);
    }
```

And this is the JSON I'm using in the body of the POST request:

```
{
    "titulo": "Git",
    "nivel": "Intermedio",
    "nhoras": "12",
    "profesorid": 1581068174
}
```

All the other parameters are arriving correctly and the object arrives to the database, but with the `profesorid` with *null* value. I stopped the execution y this *addCurso* method and the value of *profesorid* is null. The *id* value is not being sent in the request because it is setted before saving in the database.
Please, anyone can help me and say what is failing here? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: For Firefox exists a plugin called "Tamper Data".  For Chrome called it "Tamper Chrome". With it you can check if your parameter will be sended to your REST controller or not.

Comment: Always let your `getters` and `setters` get generated, don't type them by hand.

Comment: There is another potential issue here: JSON allows numbers to be any size, and depending on JSON framework this will eventaully be an issue. Most frameworks probably use Long (etc) for numbers, and then you should be fine. But if you get strange errors where the Id:s are translated to completely different number, you need to send them as Strings in JSON and do the Long->String->Long conversion using eg @JsonSerialize for Jackson.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public void setProfesorid(Long profesor) {
    this.profesorid = profesorid;
}
```

Look at this setter. You've made a mistake here.

It should be

```
public void setProfesorid(Long profesor) {
    this.profesorid = profesor;
}
```